# Match sentences and whitespace separately

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Take the following text:

```
This is a sentence. This is a sentence...    This is a sentence! This is a sentence? This is a sentence.This is a sentence. This is a sentence
```

I'd like to match this so I have an array like the following:

```
[
  "This is a sentence.",
  " ",
  "This is a sentence...",
  "    ",
  "This is a sentence!",
  " ",
  "This is a sentence?",
  " ",
  "This is a sentence.",
  "",
  "This is a sentence.",
  " ",
  "This is a sentence",
]
```

With my current regex, however:

```
str.match(/[^.!?]+[.!?]*(\s*)/g);
```

I get the following:

```
[
  "This is a sentence. ",
  "This is a sentence...    ", 
  "This is a sentence! ",
  "This is a sentence? ", 
  "This is a sentence.", 
  "This is a sentence. ", 
  "This is a sentence"
]
```

How can I achieve this with JS ReExp?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `s.match(/[^.!?\s](?:[^.!?]*[^.!?\s])?[.!?]*|\s*(?!\s*$)/g)`?

Comment: How many sentences are inside this portion? `This is a sentence. This is a sentence...`

Comment: @im_tsm 2 sentences with one space in between. `["This is a sentence.", " ", "This is a sentence..."]`

Comment: Please note: I copied the wrong current regex. I've updated it to `str.match(/[^.!?]+[.!?]*(\s*)/g);`

Comment: do you need array of sentences or whitespace in the result array matter too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `[^\s]` at the beginning and change `(\s*)` to `|\s+`.

The final regex will be like:

`str.match(/[^\s][^.!?]+[.!?]*|\s+/g)`

- `[^\s]` will remove white spaces from the beginning of the expression
- `|\s+` will treat white spaces as a new expression

Comment: Yes! That works! Thank you for your explanation too. And welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0):

here is solution using you regex in the question, but doing some array spliting afterwards to keep the whitespaces in the array; essentially it will split the array by white spaces if they are in the end of the string ( positive lookahead of `$` ) then flatting it again to achieve the exact output you want .

```js
const baseStr = "This is a sentence. This is a sentence...    This is a sentence! This is a sentence? This is a sentence.This is a sentence. This is a sentence";

var result = baseStr.match(/[^.!?]+[.!?]*(\s*)/g).map( str => str.split(/(\s*)(?=$)/).filter(_=>_)).flat();

console.log(result);
```